# Has anyone done the Linq 101 samples with Lambda syntax?

Tags: linq, lambda

Has anyone done the job of translating the [101 Linq samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) published by Microsoft to Lambda syntax?

If no, does anyone know a site to use as starting point for learning Linq Lambda syntax? I liked the format of the 101 Linq samples, so something similar would be appreciated.

Comment: Not everything is better in lambda syntax... particularly joins

Comment: Many things are though. Well that's what I find.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally got around to do this job myself :-) All 101 samples are now converted to Lambda/Fluent syntax and published at [Linq101.nilzorblog.com](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to learn lambda syntax, download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). Then write the normal syntax 
Eg:

```
from f in Features
where f.Id > 0
select f
```

Then run it, and at the bottom you'll see "Results lambda SQL IL" Simply click on the Lambda, and you'll see:

```
Features.Where(f => (f.Id > 0))
```

It doesn't always produce the cleanest syntax, but it is a way to learn the lambda syntax.

Comment: LinqPad is a good tool to learn Linq, I agree, but I'm more looking for some sort of reference document or web site. That said, maybe I could translate the 101 samples using LinqPad myself and publish it :)

Comment: I second @Taylor's recommendation and encourage you to try translating some of them yourself. Often the best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: I know you're looking for some kind of reference document, but 100% honest, LinqPad was a big help when I broke down and learned Lambda.  It was about a day or so and I really started to get the hang of it.